# "Operation not permitted" when installing moduce on macOS

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I wish to install:

```
https://github.com/jdennis/keycloak-httpd-client-install
```

And tried to do so via:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

but I get:

```
creating /usr/share/keycloak-httpd-client-install
error: could not create '/usr/share/keycloak-httpd-client-install': Operation not permitted
```

What should I be doing?

Comment: The path */usr/share* is under [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) (SIP), which prevents modification of specified system paths and files. The installer needs to be changed to use a different path such as */usr/local/share*. You could disable SIP by booting into recovery mode, and then install, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Indeed, pip install gives `ValueError: path '/usr/share/keycloak-httpd-client-install/templates' cannot be absolute`. The package is buggy.